# nextLine() in java cannot get the exactly value I want

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print("Type new, wil display TRUE:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = sc.nextLine();

    if(userInput=="new"){
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    }else {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }
}
```

I have no idea why new not equals to new.

Please give me some hints :)

Comment: comparing string with equals is good rather than using ==

Comment: == compares memory allocation position, whereas String.equals(anotherString) compares memory stored value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `userInput.equals("new")` instead.

This explains everything: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It really works! thanks a lot!!